# Passing Value to Parent Function With a Callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, asynchronous

I'd like the emailExists() function to return either true of false when called, the error I'm getting is:

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
```

Async and callbacks are both pretty new to me, and I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake. I've modeled this after another StackOverflow answer to a similar question and from what I can tell, it should be working.

Here's my code:

```
var emailExists = function(cb) {

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, existingUser) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (existingUser) {
            cb(true);
        } else {
            cb(false);
        }
    });

}
verifyEmail( emailExists() );
```

Thanks!

Comment: You should use cb in inner scope just pass the callback as parameter to inner function

Comment: `emailexists` expects a param, which you dont seem to provide (unless `verifyEmail` binds it).

Comment: @Dementic - No, there's no need for that `return`.

Comment: Is it Mongoose? The question should state this explicitly because this is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is there because no `cb` was passed to the function. It should be provided, and then the result should be provided to a function that depends on it, `verifyEmail`:

```
emailExists(result => {
  // depends on how verifyEmail works
  verifyEmail(result);
});
```

Errors should also be handled. There may be problems because `req` and `next` may not be available in the scope of `emailExists` (they preferably should not be).

Callbacks aren't needed in the first place. Mongoose supports promises, and callback-based API is legacy.

It should be:

```
var emailExists = function(email ) {
  return User.findOne({ email })
  .then(existingUser => !!existingUser);
}
```

And can be used with errors being consistently handled:

```
emailExists(req.body.email)
.then(result => {
  // depends on how verifyEmail works
  verifyEmail(result);
})
.catch(err => {
  next(err);
});
```

Comment: This is way better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed callback function to the code. Do like this

```
var emailExists = function(cb) {

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, existingUser) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        if (existingUser) {
            cb(true);
        } else {
            cb(false);
        }
    });

}

//callback is a refrence of function .

verifyEmail( emailExists(function(status){

 // do your operation here
 Console.log('the output is '+status);
}) );
```